# Is there any rails gem that is similar to the Android Priority Jobqueue library?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I need task/job queue gem that is similar to [this](https://github.com/yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) android library, but for rails. I also don't mind writing the code myself/from scratch if there's no alternative.

These are the features I need:

1. I need the queue to be "app-wide", so that I can add tasks to it
   from any controller.
2. I need to be able to set the maximum number of tasks the queue can process at a time.
3. I'd also like for it to allow me to set priority on tasks so that a more important one would be processed before a less important one.

What I'm trying to build uses twilio to send text messages to users. And Twilio has limits as to how many message one can send in a second. I need to be able to just call a method `.send_message` that automatically just adds the message to the queue and it waits it's turn.

Comment: I'm using delayed_job gem for the same features that you need in your application. It had been reliable so far.

Comment: I like delayed_job, too. One quirk is that when it queues up arguments, anything that's an ActiveRecord is serialized to just it's type and id.  Then when the job runs, it does a lookup to get the AR content.  The impact is that you need to `.save` any AR the task will use before starting it. This makes sense because DJ was invented to maintain document queues, and this saves double-storing the documents.  But it's inconvenient in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) has most of the functionality you want.

You can set different priority, different queues and it is all backed by Redis so you entire application can share the queue.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) it has many levels of support you can start with the [free one](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) before upgrading

Here is a [video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/366-sidekiq) on how to set it up and use it as well